# Nginx redirect to backend-nginx server returns wrong port

Tags: docker, nginx

I am working on some docker containers, Where there is a "main" nginx host that then proxies to other nginx hosts

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mcaq.me www.mcaq.me files.mcaq.me dev.mcaq.me priv.mcaq.me;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://mcaq:8080;
        proxy_redirect http://mcaq:8080/;
        proxy_set_header    Host                   $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP              $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto      $scheme;
    }
}
```

This (above) is the main nginx container

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    index index.html index.php;
    server_name mcaq.me www.mcaq.me;
    root /code;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

This (above) is an example of one of the sub-nginx containers
The main nginx server is being controlled by certbot after running, so is actually listening on 443 ssl
This behaves as I expect, when connecting to https://mcaq.me/
Then, when going to https://mcaq.me/portfolio, it breaks

It shows the 8080 port, which I don't understand
If you instead do https://mcaq.me/portfolio/
It works as expected
I've tried different things like using proxy_redirect, but I am struggling to find a solution, or understand what the problem is
Any advice, or if you need more infomation, let me know. cheers!

Comment: I think it's a regex mistake 'fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;' ask for a final "/".
And I'm not sure you should use 'proxy_redirect' here. It acts like a "url rewriting" and I'm not sure the use case here need this.

Comment: I tried this and did not get anywhere. I'm not quite sure what you meant. Can you suggest anything else?